# jenkins can't find the job when build job, why?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

when run the command like

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://192.168.9.199:8080 list-jobs --username admin --password 'admin'
```

the result is :

```
testjob
```

but run

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://192.168.9.199:8080 build testjob --username admin --password 'admin'

No such job 'testjob'
```

why does it not find the 'testjob' ?

Comment: Your admin user has full permissions on your Jenkins server? On the testjob, did you set some specific permissions?

Comment: I can use admin build the job on the web page

Answer (score 4):

I had the same behavior and found out that allowing *anonymous read access* in the *global security* section fixed it. It is still mandatory to specify `--username` and `--password` to access the resource.

[image: allow anonymous read access]

Answer (score 1):

Just for future searchs:

As described [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43346%22here%22%22):

> If you use the API token, what is the recommendation here use the command below and it will work:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.example:8080/ -auth admin:2793b5e799cac2ec343245e2384f06fc build testing
```